# i want run php page after another page run in cron

Tags: php, curl, cron

i have a jobs in crontab and i want run page after another page is  run

```
 * * * * * curl http://127.0.0.1/page1.php >/dev/null 2>&1 
 * * * * * sleep 10;curl http://127.0.0.1/page1.php >/dev/null 2>&1 
 * * * * * sleep 20;curl http://127.0.0.1/page1.php >/dev/null 2>&1 
 * * * * * sleep 30;curl http://127.0.0.1/page1.php >/dev/null 2>&1 
 * * * * * sleep 40;curl http://127.0.0.1/page1.php >/dev/null 2>&1 
 * * * * * sleep 50;curl http://127.0.0.1/page1.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

when this page is run complete

```
* * * * * curl http://127.0.0.1/page1.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

i want run this

`* * * * * sleep 10;curl http://127.0.0.1/page1.php >/dev/null 2>&1`

and run  next

```
...
```

Comment: Create a simple bash script with each curl command in succession then execute the bash script.

Comment: but the same page open after 10 seconds same problem

Comment: ... because you're running curl on the same url?